# How do I make OKTA redirect a parameterized URL correctly?

Tags: redirect, okta, mellon

TLDR: I have a site protected with Okta SAML authentication, but somehow during my redirect and authentication phase, the redirect, which is a parameter in the URL, gets lost. Looking for advice.

Background:
I have a Linux server with Apache using Mellon to connect to Okta for SAML authentication.

I have a url like this:

`https://docs.example.com/current/readme`

I have a redirect.php file at the root of example.com that redirects the user to something like

`https://docs.example.com/docs/version/Default.php#cshid=readme`

That is the generated output URL for context-sensitive help, which in turn redirects the user to something like:

`https://docs.example.com/docs/version/content/readme.php`

That all works if you are already authenticated with SAML. However, if you aren't already authenticated, you get sent to Okta.

```
https://success.example.com/login/login.htm?fromURI=%2Fapp%2Fssoexample_docsexamplecom_2%2Fexk4g2c3ofeuJWRSu4x6%2Fsso%2Fsaml%3FSAMLRequest%3DhZJfT8IwFMW%252FytJ3aBljaAMkAyTBqDHgn8QX0pSLNG7t7G0Rv73tFhVf8KnN7Tm553fSEYqqrHnh3V6v4N0DuulSA3Em%252BLmymiTL%252BZhsslk6HE6nxbTH8sHVIOvnLGWzxXSYXxbZBVuQ5pYanRCuzBiaa%252FD8k46eOgNOevxjL2QZB4YlBauce2dq5FTil5KQOweQIud6kpTUW2TUji%252BZa%252Bp7Jsd%252BOvkycxohJjhHK1sRVx6a8PZUVVdKqkcSRbGSmhKH5OdKBEi2n1oRx3gZ1J8lxWX%252BQrsGuxBSXhc3fyCxdynVBWUpdG0NuhWgHVMQCajGJo35dnJeeeInmpH7fe4C2jL%252Bb0J6T9j9kr8Qx4natvZNVLurNCoQgOBKez4mFkQLnA664HQSbvy7yecfAE%253D%26RelayState%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdocs.example.com%252FDocs%252Fcurrent%252FTopNav%252FDefault.php#cshid=readme
```

So, at the end of that URL, the hash and parameter are retained: `#cshid=readme`

However, after I successfully log in, somehow the URL looses the `#cshid=readme` and just redirects me to:

`https://docs.example.com/docs/version/Default.php`

Any ideas how I can make it retain the hash and the content after the hash? I'm not the person who configured mellon or Okta, but I'd like to have a solution in mind before I contact them with my issue.

Comment: Try to see on which step your hash part is dropped. That will help you to identify, which product is responsible for that redirect, where it gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across a similar issue, there are a couple of possible solutions to these scenarios.

- Replacing the **#** with **?**. In this context, https://docs.example.com/docs/version/Default.php?cshid=readme
- Encoding the **#** as **%23** (still not likely to work in most cases). https://docs.example.com/docs/version/Default.php%23cshid=readme

It is expected that everything after the **#** is dropped. Fragment parameters are used only on the client-side, but the server will ignore it, which is why Okta is ignoring that portion of the URL.

Using **?** instead of **#** will usually solve most issues.